# Two pages have same title, same description, different content. Are they duplicates?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, duplicate-content, meta-tags

We have release our website from our mobile app in a very short amount of time.
The website is quite good, but not at all optimized for SEO. For example, there is absolutely no care for meta tags. All pages have the same meta tags.

I have tried to ask indexing some pages by google, but google tell me that all my pages are duplicates. It is weird because the content is very different. Even when I make a live test on the google search console, I can see that google is able to fetch the 2 pages, and the content is very different, from the screenshot and the HTML it retrieves.

Here are the 2 pages:

- Homepage https://doyouno.fr/
- One item https://doyouno.fr/professionals/57a0bdf0f429f40b7c34df9d

I came to the conclusion that maybe google didn't look too deep into the content when the meta (title, description, etc.?) are the same.

Can this be the problem? What is the algorithm that makes google think 2 pages are duplicates?

Comment: It is SEO 101 to create unique descriptive titles for every page on your site.  Not doing so is a huge mistake.  Not only because of this issue, but because you are missing the opportunity to optimize your inner pages for their important keywords.   The title is the place that Google assigns the most relevancy to keywords.  More than any other place on the page.   If you only use the same word in the title of every single page, you are really missing out.

Comment: Thank you, this is completely true. I try to fix error one step at a time, and yeah, title should be the first step!

Comment: "but google tell me that all my pages are duplicates." - is it stating this as warning/error in GSC?

Comment: The error is `Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical. Status: Excluded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pages seem to be entirely generated by JavaScript. The HTML source (which is also very minimal) is *identical* on all pages, even the OG meta tags for URL etc. are the same.

Whilst Google does indeed render and index JavaScript generated content (to some degree), it is most probably the *identical* (literally "identical") HTML source that the Google tool is tripping up on.

Maybe this is a bug with the tool and Google will go ahead and index the JS generated content (despite the duplicate warnings); only time will tell. But other search engines will certainly have trouble indexing this content.

As @Stephen pointed out in comments, the duplicated meta tags will still be a problem. Particularly for social media. You don't appear to have a standard meta description tag (just the OG version) - which is good in this instance. Duplicate meta `description` tags would be worse than no meta `description` tag (as Google should generate this content in the SERPs).

You also appear to have a bunch of generated (nested) `iframe` tags - but maybe that is to do with the maps (I only had a very quick look)?